# ¿Cómo puedo establecer dos delimitadores AND para un for /F?

Tags: cmd

Si hago en CMD un `for` tal que así:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%g in (test.txt) do (
    echo %%g es el label y %%h es el valor
)
```

Con esos delimitadores lo que me pasa es que me separa por dos puntos O por espacio. Pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que separe por dos puntos Y por espacio siempre?

Comment: Al parecer no es posible usar más de un carácter para delimitar cadenas: [enlace]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690206/delims-more-then-1-character-as-delimiter[enlace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la información de este [enlace](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) tendría que delimitarte en ambos casos. También advierte que establecer más de un delimitador puede tener problemas con algunos conjuntos de datos.

Hice esta prueba en un CMD de windows 10 y funciona:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=: " %%g in ("abcd efg:hijk lmno:pqr") do (
    echo %%g primero %%h segundo %%i tercero
)
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias :)